# How to get the point clouds in a region of kinect frame?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
In my work, I need to crop point clouds in a rectangle fixed region (x0, y0, width, height) from the whole frame clouds collected by Kinect. How can I do that? I appreciate any help.
Regards,
Phuoc Nguyen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10520/how-to-get-the-point-clouds-in-a-region-of-kinect-frame?/) by [Phuoc Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/801/phuoc-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [passthrough filter in PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php#passthrough). (If you're in ROS, [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) will be handy).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0